# Android: why is my linearlayout crashing when switching at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-linearlayout

when user presses a button i would like to switch to the 'details' layout which is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:text="Category" />      

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_category" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how i am trying to switch it:

```
 switch(item.getItemId())
                {
                case ID_DETAILS:
                    // show new layout to for details                   
                    LinearLayout detailsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDetails);
                    LayoutInflater detailsvi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View detailsv = detailsvi.inflate(R.layout.activity_details, null);

// IT CRASHES ON THIS LINE
                    detailsLayout.addView(detailsv,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(detailsLayout.getLayoutParams().width, detailsLayout.getLayoutParams().height));

                            return true;
}
```

It gives a null pointer exception error!!!

```
08-09 17:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 17:23:47.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1572): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Does "R.layout.activity_details" exist?

Comment: yes, the xml that i pasted above is indeed from activity_details :)

Comment: Follow the steps below than break out of your loop and tell us what happend.

Comment: Just double checking. Try with a breakpoint

Comment: infinite loop the most important thing you need to do is run the debugger.  Trust us on this one.

Comment: just rightclick the line number.  The when you run app run in debug mode.  this will tell all. Hover over the value and you will see.

Comment: Huh!!! it says "detailsLayout=null"!!!!

Comment: and i can see 'layoutDetails' in R.java file.

Comment: Perhaps you did not setContentView(R.layout.layoutname) to the layout that contains detailsLayout PRIOR to this call.  Its either that or you did not id details layout correctly in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you solve this:

1) put a breakpoint on the crashline and run in debug mode.  You can immediately see if detailsLayout is null or not.  If not do step 2  Also check if detailsv is null.

2)   details
     Object o1 = etailsLayout.getLayoutParams();  // check if this is null.

It has to be one or the other.

Update: Since its detailsLayout is in fact null.  It must be that either

1) setContentView was not called prior to requsting detailsLayout, or
2) setContentView was set to a layout that did not define detailsLayout, or
3) setContentView was called correctly but detailsLayout is not correctly id in that layout file.

It must be one of these three.